# Managing Multiple Users on a server using IP Addresses

Tags: java, networking

I have a game that is going to use a server to handle multiplayer. The game is turn based but with turns taken simultaneously. Initially I thought I should use a separate thread for each user but I realised that I could simplify by just tracking each user based on their IP. Is this possible or would it lead to issues with dynamic IPs or people playing from the same location?

Answer (score 1):

This could lead to problems because some ISPs, such as AOL, aggregate traffic for multiple users through a single IP.  If you track both the client's IP and the client's port number, though, that should be sufficient.